How to integrate trading view with custom data feed in react?
I am trying to integrate trading view chart with my custom data to build candle chart. But, all I see is wrong candle chart data. Below is what I have tried
declare global {
    interface Window {
        TradingView: any;
    }
}

let tvScriptLoadingPromise: Promise<void>;

const PriceChart: React.FC<PieChartProps> = ({ selectedMarketIndex, marketSymbol }) => {
    const onLoadScriptRef = useRef<(() => void) | null>(null);

    const fetchOHLCData = useCallback(async () => {
        console.log(selectedMarketIndex, marketSymbol)
        try {
            const response = await getCandlesData(marketSymbol, selectedMarketIndex, '2024');
            return response.map((row: Record<string, string>) => ({
                time: parseInt(row.start)/1000,
                open: parseFloat(row.fillOpen),
                high: parseFloat(row.fillHigh),
                low: parseFloat(row.fillLow),
                close: parseFloat(row.fillClose),
            }));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching OHLC data:', error);
            return [];
        }
    }, [marketSymbol, selectedMarketIndex]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("HERE")
        onLoadScriptRef.current = createWidget;

        if (!tvScriptLoadingPromise) {
            tvScriptLoadingPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.id = 'tradingview-widget-loading-script';
                script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js';
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.onload = () => resolve();

                document.head.appendChild(script);
            });
        }

        tvScriptLoadingPromise.then(() => {
            if (onLoadScriptRef.current) {
                onLoadScriptRef.current();
            }
        });

        return () => {
            onLoadScriptRef.current = null;
        };

        function createWidget() {
            console.log("Inside createWidget")
            if (document.getElementById('tradingview') && window.TradingView) {
                new window.TradingView.widget({
                    autosize: true,
                    symbol: marketSymbol.toLowerCase().includes('perp') ? marketSymbol.split('-')[0] + '/USDC' : marketSymbol ,
                    interval: 'D',
                    timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
                    theme: 'dark',
                    style: '1',
                    locale: 'en',
                    toolbar_bg: '#333',
                    enable_publishing: false,
                    allow_symbol_change: true,
                    container_id: 'tradingview',
                    datafeed: {
                        onReady: (callback) => {
                            console.log("Datafeed is ready");
                            callback({
                                supports_search: true,
                                supports_group_request: false,
                                supports_marks: true,
                                supports_timescale_marks: true,
                                supports_time: true,
                            });
                        },
                        resolveSymbol: (symbolName, onSymbolResolvedCallback) => {
                            console.log("Resolving symbol:", symbolName);
                            onSymbolResolvedCallback({
                                name: symbolName,
                                full_name: symbolName,
                                description: 'Symbol description',
                                pricescale: 100,
                                minmov: 1,
                                has_intraday: true,
                                has_no_volume: false,
                                type: 'crypto',
                                timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
                            });
                        },
                        getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, from, to, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
                            console.log("Fetching bars:", { from, to, resolution });
                            try {
                                const ohlcData = await fetchOHLCData();
                                if (!ohlcData || ohlcData.length === 0) {
                                    onErrorCallback('No data available');
                                } else {
                                    onHistoryCallback(ohlcData, { noData: false });
                                }
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.error('Error in getBars:', error);
                                onErrorCallback('Error fetching data');
                            }
                        },
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    }, [marketSymbol, fetchOHLCData]);

    return (
        <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
            <div className={styles.tradingview} id="tradingview" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default PriceChart;

It appears as if my custom data is not even being fetched because I do not see any console logs from the functions onReady, resolveSymbol, getBars inside datafeed.
Maybe I am not integrating the tradingview component properly and I cannot find any example in react.
